# How to line up an image that is inside a list with the rest of the list in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have a list with two text objects, an image, and a button. Everything lines up fine when I remove the image. I've tried adjusting the margin of only the image but, that just moves the entire list. Is this the best way to go about this?

I do realize that you aren't supposed to have any other tags between the ul and li tags. I just want to get through this before cleaning that up.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <span class="left-align">
      <li><a href="pages/about.html" class="black-font">About</a></li>

      <li><a href="pages/store.html" class="black-font">Store</a></li>
    </span>
    <span class="right-align">
      <li><a href="pages/gmail.html" class="black-font">Gmail</a></li>

      <li><a href="pages/images.html" class="black-font">Images</a></li>

      <li><a href="pages/apps.html"><img src="./Images/apps.png" alt="Apps Icon" style="width:35px;height:35px"
            class="apps-button"> </a></li>

      <li><button type="button">Sign In</button></li>
    </span>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    }

.right-align {
    float: right;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin: 13px 0 0 10px;
}

.apps-button {
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.left-align {
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin: 13px 0 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is correction to your code.

Note : You can't use span in between `ul` and `li` tag because its tree model it should be

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

You can use `<span>` or any other tag inside `<li>` tag. Based on your question given correction to answer.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
}
ul.right-menu{
float:right;
}
ul.left-menu{
margin-top:10px;
}
li {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right-align {
  float: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin: 13px 0 0 10px;
}

.apps-button {
width:20px;height:20px
}

.left-align {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin: 13px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="left-menu">

    <li><a href="pages/about.html" class="black-font">About</a></li>

    <li><a href="pages/store.html" class="black-font">Store</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right-menu">
    <li><a href="pages/gmail.html" class="black-font">Gmail</a></li>

    <li><a href="pages/images.html" class="black-font">Images</a></li>

    <li>
      <a href="pages/apps.html"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/2018-social-media-logotypes/1000/2018_social_media_popular_app_logo_instagram-256.png" alt="Apps Icon" style="" class="apps-button"> </a>
    </li>

    <li><button type="button">Sign In</button></li>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the pixel size of the png file. It may be that the pixel size is larger than what you need.